# How to remove the white space from a dynamic php bootstrap image gallery?

Tags: php, html, css, whitespace

This is what I am currently seeing.  The yellow cross is the white space I would like to fill.

[image: This is what I am currently seeing. The yellow cross is the white space I would like to fill.]

I am looking to remove the white space from a php/boostrap image gallery.
Is there a simple solution? Am I missing something?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_uploads WHERE memberID = $memberid";
    $result = mysqli_query($databaseconnection, $sql);
    $images = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $images[] = $row;
    }
    mysqli_close($databaseconnection);
    $y = 1;

    foreach ($images as $image) :
        if ($y > 0) {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding: 5px;">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded shadow-lg" src="images/'. $image["image_url"] .'">
        </div>';

        }
    ?>
        
    <?php
    
        $y++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use 3 backticks for code block and it would be really helpful if you can format your code using 4 spaces

Comment: @Chandan Thank you for your reply.  Please can you expand what you mean?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always will have a black space if you don't upload the image in same size.

but there is always a solution.

If you don't wanna use any third party css and js u can use images in background to remove white space.

```
<style>
    .image-gallery{
        background-size: cover!important;
        background-position: center!important;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_uploads WHERE memberID = $memberid";
    $result = mysqli_query($databaseconnection, $sql);
    $images = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $images[] = $row;
    }
    mysqli_close($databaseconnection);
    $y = 1;

    foreach ($images as $image) :
        if ($y > 0) {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 image-gallery" style="padding: 5px;baclground: url(images/'. $image["image_url"] .')"></div>';

        }
    ?>
        
    <?php
    
        $y++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
```

Or you ca use Masonry Layout https://codepen.io/Harpreet-Singh-Dhot/pen/ZEpvBqr